# How do I update or insert an sqlite row with multiple conditions

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables. A, B, and A_to_B. The relationship between A and B is many-to-many. This relationship information is stored in table A_to_B. It's construction is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
 identifier_from_a TEXT NOT NULL,
 identifier_from_b TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Each relationship is unique.

I would like to persist my relationship data with a single statement per relationship. My question is, how can I achieve this without inserting duplicates?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you are trying to solve? Specifically, this part is not clear to me: "persist my relationship data with a single statement per relationship". Why would you persist it with anything but a single statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a multiple column UNIQUE definition in the create table statement.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
 identifier_from_a TEXT NOT NULL,
 identifier_from_b TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (a,b) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
```